# Computation of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx \cdot \sin ny}{n^2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, complex-numbers, summation

First I used the identity
$$\sin nx \cdot \sin ny=\cos(n(x-y))-\cos(n(x+y))$$
and the sum turned into the following
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx \cdot \sin ny}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n(x-y))}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n(x+y))}{n^2}$$
because both series converge. And now we have to calculate the two sums above that have the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(na)}{n^2}$$ for $a\in \mathbb R$. Then I tried the following:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(na)}{n^2}=\textrm{Re}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ina}}{n^2}$$
but then things are getting a bit difficult because the function $\textrm{Li}_2(z)$ appears and I don't know how to handle it from there...
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Probably there is no simpler answer than the one involving the dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_2$  You can write it in terms of hypergeometric ${}_3F_2(1,1,1;2,2;e^{ix})$.

Answer (score 8):

Using the physicist's approach, you can view this as an expansion in the eigenvectors of the second derivative with Dirichlet boundary conditions on the domain $[0,\pi]$:
$$
e_n = \sin (nx) \\
e_n(0)=e_n(\pi)=0 \\
-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e_n = -n^2e_n
$$
In particular, you have the resolution of unity:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(nx)\sin(ny) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}\delta(x-y-m\pi)-\delta(x+y-m\pi)
$$
You could also prove it using the Poisson summation formula, or physically, the method of images. The kernel is related to your function:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)\sin(ny)}{n^2} \\
-\partial_x^2f &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)\sin(ny) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}\delta(x-y-m\pi)-\delta(x+y-m\pi)
\end{align}
$$
You can solve this to find a triangular wave. Explicitly, for $x,y\in[0,\pi]$, with no loss of generality by periodising (with a possible sign):
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{(\pi-y)x}{2} & x\leq y \\
\frac{y(\pi-x)}{2} & y\leq x
\end{cases}
$$
You can easily check this formula numerically.

Alternatively, you can view this as the Green’s function of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $[0,\pi]$. This is usually how you come up with these kind of sums.

Btw, as a sanity check, you can check the consistency of the result with the Basel problem. For example, setting $x=y=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the formula gives:
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb N, \text{ $n$ odd}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$
This is consistent with the Basel problem:
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
\sum_{n\in \mathbb N, \text{ $n$ even}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{24}
$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can make use of Feynman's trick here. Noting that
$$ f(a) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(na)}{n^2}. $$
You have
$$ f''(a) = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(na) = -\Re \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{ina} =  \frac{1}{2} $$
Solving this differential equation gives $f(a) = \frac{1}{4} a^2 - \frac{1}{2} \pi a + \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. This seems to work for the values of $a$ that I tried, but I am not sure about the rigor of summing the cosine series.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out, the function $f$ is definitely $2\pi$ periodic and that should be reflected in the resulting formula. So the solution is valid on $a \in [0,2\pi]$, but extending it by $a \to a \bmod 2\pi$ seems to work well.

[image: Numerical vs. Analytical comparison]

Comment: The function $f$ is certainly $2\pi$-periodic, so this argument cannot work for all $a$. I am also don't really understand how did you get $1/2$ for the sum of cosines.

Comment: If you mod the function by $2\pi$ doesn't it work? I agree it is not rigorous, but I plotted against the numerical sum in Mathematica and the agreement is perfect.

Comment: Your result is not correct, your sum of cosines is rather:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(nx)=-1+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}\delta(x-\pi m)$$ This is consistent with your average value over a period $\pi$ which you took to be $-\frac{1}{2}$. However, both functions are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$F(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin nx\sin ny\over n^2}$$ By periodicity with respect to $x,$  $y$  and  the property $F(-x,y)=F(x,-y)=-F(x,y),$  we may restrict to  $0<x, y<\pi.$

Let
$f_x=\boldsymbol 1_{(-x,x)}.$ The sine Fourier coefficients of $f_x$ vanish. The cosine  Fourier coefficients of $f_x$ are equal $$a_0={1\over \pi}\int\limits_{-x}^x\,du={2\over \pi}x,\quad \  a_n={1\over \pi}\int\limits_{-x}^x\cos nu\,du={2\over \pi n}\sin nx$$
By the [Parseval identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)
$${2\min(x,y)\over \pi}={1\over \pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f_x(u)f_y(y)\,du ={2\over \pi^2}xy+\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4\over \pi^2n^2}\sin nx\sin ny$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin nx\sin ny\over n^2}= {\pi\over 2}\min(x,y)-{1\over 2}xy,\quad 0\le x,y\le \pi$$

Answer (score 0):

There are already amazing and insightful answers. But I'd like to add a more "conventional" answer, just based on basic knowledge of the polylogarithm function $\mathrm{Li}_2(z)$.

Your direction of using the polylogarithm is correct, but it could be more direct when you write $\sin$ in terms of $\exp$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx \cdot \sin ny}{n^2} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm i nx}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm -i nx}}{2\mathrm i} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm i ny}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm -i n y}}{2\mathrm i}\\
&= -\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n(x+y)}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n(x-y)}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} n(x-y)}+\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} n(x+y)} \right)
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$
Of course you know the definition of the polylogarithm (the series converges for $|z|\leqslant 1$, then our method works):
$$
\mathrm{Li}_2(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}, \tag{2}
$$
therefore the series now becomes
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx \cdot \sin ny}{n^2} = -\frac{1}{4}\left[\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i (x+y)}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i (x-y)}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i (x-y)}\right)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i (x+y)}\right) \right] \tag{3}
$$
If you go to [Wikipedia page of Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions), you will find a magical formula:
$$
\mathrm{Li}_2(\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}x})+\mathrm{Li}_2(\mathrm{e}^{-2 \pi \mathrm{i}x})=2\pi^2 B_2(x)= 2 \pi ^2 \left(x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}\right)
$$
An intuitive way of proving this is taking the derivative twice. Denote the L.H.S  as $l(x)$, then by [properties of derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Properties) of polylogarithm, we have
$$
l''(x) = 4\pi^2.
$$
Noticing that $l(x=0)=l(x=1)=2 \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$, integral constants can be determined.

It should be mentioned that this relation is valid only for $x \in [0,1]$, and its values for other $x$ can be obtained by translation.

Back to the problem, we can group terms in $(3)$ and get
$$
\frac{| x-y| ^2}{8}-\frac{\pi  | x-y| }{4}+\frac{\pi  | x+y| }{4}-\frac{| x+y| ^2}{8}\tag{4}
$$
for $x,y \in [0,\pi]$.

Assuming $x>y$ or $x<y$, we can get formulas explicit piecewise expressions in existing answers.

Here's what the function looks like (plotted directly and partial sum as a numerical check.)
[image: Plot of the summation result]
[image: Plot of the partial sum as a check]